# ObjectBox: switch from local db to sync and back

Tags: objectbox

Consider an app that can be used offline on one device to begin with. Later, if the user chose to sync to other devices, how would that transition take place? A simple setting, or a migration?

Now consider a user who decides not to use sync anymore and wants to simply use a local db on one device. Same question: how would that transition take place?

Researching the topic prior to db selection.

Comment: This seems to somewhat imply that user-specific data exists. This is currently not supported when using ObjectBox Sync (e.g. all clients have the same data). See https://objectbox.io/sync/ on what use cases are supported.